# Let $X∼U[0,1]$ and $Y=X^2$ then prove that $\mathbb E(Y)=\frac13$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X∼U[0,1]$ and $Y=X^2$ then prove that $\mathbb E(Y)=\frac13$ directly from the definition of expectation, here is the *definition of expectation*,

> If X only takes finitely many values $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, and $A_i=\{\omega:X(\omega)=x_i\}$, define the *simple expectation* of $X$ by $$\mathbb E\: X=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\mathbb P(A_i)$$

I get the manual solution,

> You need to define $Y_n=\frac{k}{n}$ when $Y\in\left[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}\right]$, for $k\in\{0,\cdots,n-1\}$, and $Z_n=\frac{k+1}{n}$ when $Y\in\left[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}\right]$ , for $k\in\{0,\cdots,n-1\}$. Show that $\mathbb E(Y_n)$ and $\mathbb E(Z_n)$. Define $L=\sup\{\mathbb E\:Z:Z\textrm{ is simple}, Z\leq Y \textrm{ a.s.}\}$ and $U=\inf\{\mathbb E\:Z:Z\textrm{ is simple}, Z\geq Y \textrm{ a.s.}\}$. Using $L$ and $U$ properly with the limit on $\frac1n$

But I didn't understand how the solution use the definition. And to be honest, I didn't understand the solution as well. It will be a great help if anyone help me to understand the solution completely.

Comment: Hello :) $X$ is not a discrete random variable. This is the reason, why you need to integrate and not to sum up. You have to calculate $$\int_0^1x^2\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Note that your definition is ONLY if $X$ takes on only finitely many values.  For a continuous random variable, you need to use $E(X)=\int_{\mathbb R} xf_X(x)dx$ where $f_X(x)$ is the pdf of $X$.

Comment: I understand the random variable is not discrete but the solution was confusing to me. @Jochen

Comment: Then how could you justify the manual solution? @Aaron. The problem is I am not enough familiar with measure theory. And the solution is way to more complicated for me. It will be great help if you breakdown the solution.

Comment: Probably the solution is to define sequences $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb N_+}, (Z_n)_{n \in \mathbb N_+}$ of random variables taking only finitelly many values such that $Y_n \le Y \le Z_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb N_+$. Then by monotonicity of expectation we would have $\mathbb E[Y_n] \le \mathbb E[Y] \le \mathbb E[Z_n]$. You can compute $\mathbb E[Y_n],\mathbb E[Z_n]$ by definition of expectation of random variables with finitelly many values and take limits to show that $\frac{1}{3} \le \mathbb E[Y] \le \frac{1}{3}$. But it is certainly an overkill here.

Comment: Yes @DominikKutek. But I need to understand this overkill process also, as the hints push me to do so in the similar fashion.

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\int_0^1 x^2 dx=\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_0^1=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: I do the same but the lecturer give me 1 out of 10 @tommik

Answer (score 1):

For this particular problem, you don't need measure theory and Lebesgue integration. You can simply use probability densities and Riemann integrals:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} yf_Y(y) \,dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty y \frac{d}{dy}\left[\mathbb{P}(X^2 \leq y)\right] \,dy \\
&= \int_{0}^1 y \frac{d}{dy}\left[\sqrt{y}\right] \,dy \\
&= \int_{0}^1 \frac{\sqrt{y}}{2} \,dy \\
&= \frac{1}{3}.
\end{align}

If you really need the measure-theoretic proof, then please try to explain which step you don't understand.

Comment: How $L=\sup\{\mathbb E\:Z:Z\textrm{ is simple}, Z\leq Y \textrm{ a.s.}\}$ and $U=\inf\{\mathbb E\:Z:Z\textrm{ is simple}, Z\geq Y \textrm{ a.s.}\}$ help to get $\mathbb E(Y)=\frac13$ @learner. It will be a great help if you explain that.

Comment: Note that you can compute $\mathbb{E}(Y_n)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Z_n)$ directly using the definition of expectation that you provided. Moreover, you have that $\mathbb{E}(Y_n) \leq \mathbb{E}(Y) \leq \mathbb{E}(Z_n)$ for all $n$ and that $Y_n, Z_n \to Y$. Now, the result follows if you can prove that both $\mathbb{E}(Y_n)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Z_n)$ converge to 1/3 as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

A probability space is a measure space $(\Omega,\mu_{\Omega})$ such that $\mu_{\Omega}(\Omega)=1$, a random variable on $\Omega$ is a measurable function $X:\Omega\to \mathbb R$, and the expected value is simply the integral, $\int_{\Omega} X(\omega)d\mu_{\Omega}(\omega)$. By using the pushforward measure, we can change perspectives integrating on $\mathbb R$ instead of on $\Omega$, and for nice random variables (where the pushforward measure is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure), we have a *density* function $f_X$, such that the pushforward measure is $f_X \mu$ where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

In the case of a uniform distribution, $X\sim U[a,b]$, the density function is $f_X=\frac{\chi_{[a,b]}}{b-a}$, and if $Y=g(X)$, $E(Y)=E(g(X))=\int_{\mathbb R} g(x)f_X(x)d\mu(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b g(x)dx$.

This would yield for our particular problem that $E(X^2)=\int_0^1 x^2 dx = 1/3$.

However, an alternative perspective is given by finding the density function for $Y=X^2$.  The pdf is the derivative of the cdf, and we can compute that for $0\leq a \leq 1$

$$\begin{split}P(Y\leq y) &= P(X^2\leq y) \\ 
                          &= P(X\leq \sqrt y) \\
                          &=\sqrt y\end{split}$$
and so $$f_Y(y)=\frac{d \sqrt y}{dy}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}.$$

We can then can then calculate $E(Y)=\int_0^1 yf_Y(y)dy=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \sqrt{y}\,dy=1/3.$  Either method can be viewed as using the definition of expected value.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to use the layer cake representation, which is given by the following: Suppose $1 \leq p < \infty$, then
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X^p|] = \int_0 ^\infty \mathbb{P}(|X^p|>x) \, dx = \int_0 ^\infty p x^{p-1} \mathbb{P}(|X|>x) \, dx. 
$$

For your question,
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] &= \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}(X^2>x) \,dx \\
&= \int_0^1 2x \mathbb{P}(X>x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^12x(1-x)\, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{3}.
\end{split} 
$$
In particular, notice that we integrated from $0$ to $1$, instead of to $\infty$. This is because $\mathbb{P}(X^2>x) = 0$ for all $x > 1$.